For custom shopify apps, how do you add app embed blocks?
I do build some custom apps for Shopify stores. However, I struggle to create App Embeds Blocks.
For a public app I can do it using the shopify cli.
How can I do the same for a custom APP?
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/build/online-store/theme-app-extensions/configuration#app-embed-blocks
